# How I can prove that the derivative of $\sin x$ is $\cos x$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

I want to prove that the derivative of $\sin x$ is $\cos x$, but how? Is this proposition true?

$$(\sin x) ^{\prime}=\cos x \Longleftrightarrow‎ \sin x ^{2}+\cos x ^{2}=1 , \forall x$$
Thank you.

Comment: Use  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html on $$\sin(x+h)-\sin x$$

Comment: Thank you. What about secand question?

Comment: Of course that proposition is true. Both sides of the implication are true! What you seem to want is to use the latter in a proof. This is a good idea.

Comment: You mean sin^2 (x) not sin (x)^2. Similarly for cos.

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x)=\sin x$$
Using first principle
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(x+h) -\sin x}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{h}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{2x-h}{2}\right)}{\frac{h}{2}}$$

Answer (score 3):

**First question**

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(x+h)-\sin x}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin x\cos h+\sin h\cos x-\sin x}h=\cos x$$

You have to assume proved the limit $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin h}h=1$. The way to do this deppends completely on how you defined $\sin$.

**Second question**

A biconditional is true when both sides are true, and when both sides are false. In this case, both sides are true, so the biconditional is true.

Comment: You also need $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\cos h - 1}{h} = 0$.

Comment: I wonder if one could do somehow with del Hospital and assuming $\sin'(x) = \cos(x)$  in a clever way to avoid circularity?? Probably not?

Answer (score 1):

Take

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x)\right) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} 1 = 0 \implies 2\cos(x)\cos(x)' + 2\sin(x)\sin(x)' = 0.  $$

Consequently,

$$ \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} = - \frac{\sin(x)'}{\cos(x)'} \quad \text{for } x \neq n \frac{\pi}{2}. $$

Hence, we must have that either

$$ \cos(x)' = -\sin(x) \quad \text{and} \quad \sin(x)' = \cos(x) $$
or
$$ \cos(x)' = \sin(x) \quad \text{and} \quad \sin(x)' = -\cos(x). $$

Geometrically, it is clear that as $x$ is increasing away from $0$ in the first quadrant, $\cos(x)$ is decreasing, i.e., $\cos(x)' < 0$. Hence, we must have that the first of the two alternatives above are correct, i.e.,
$$ \cos(x)' = - \sin(x) \quad \text{and} \quad \sin(x)' = \cos(x).  $$

The same argument can be repeated in each quadrant.

Comment: I do not see how $\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} = - \frac{\sin(x)'}{\cos(x)'}$ for $x \neq n \frac{\pi}{2}$ by itself implies that $\cos'(x)=-\sin(x)$ or $\cos'(x)=\sin(x).$ Why wouldn't the first equation be satisfied if $\cos'(x)=-x\sin(x)$ (decreasing in the first quadrant) and $\sin'(x)=x\cos(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

We know that $$ f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} f(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h) -f(x)}{h}$$
Take $$f(x)=\sin x \Leftrightarrow f(x+h) = \sin(x+h) $$
Substitute them in the fundamental relation of derivative of function with limits.
$$\frac{d}{dx} \sin x =\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(x+h) -\sin x}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2\sin \Big(\frac{h}{2}\Big)\cos\Big(\frac{2x-h}{2}\Big)}{h}$$
$$=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin \Big(\frac{h}{2}\Big)\cos\Big(\frac{2x-h}{2}\Big)}{\frac{h}{2}}$$
$$=\lim_{\frac{h}{2}\to 0}\frac{\sin \Big(\frac{h}{2}\Big)}{\frac{h}{2}} \times \lim_{h \to 0} \cos\Big(\frac{2x-h}{2}\Big)$$
$$= 1 \times \cos x = \cos x $$

You can learn the proof much clearly here

http://www.mathdoubts.com/calculus/differentiation/identity/derivative-of-sinx/

Comment: Welcome (back) to Mathematics Stack Exchange. We require that if you link to your website, you state so explicitly in your post. See [How not to be a spammer](/help/promotion).